# ActionLink optional parameter error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using the following code in a view and I am trying to add the withdraw link at the end using an additional parameter but I get the following error:

System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'personID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Withdraw(Int32, Int32)' in 'MaxMe2.Controllers.TeamController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

```
<% if(Model.departmentsDisplayCheck) {%>
<table>
    <tr>         
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Status</th> 
    </tr>

<% foreach (var dep in Model.departmentsList){ %>

    <tr>
        <td><%: Html.ActionLink(dep.Name, "Details", "Department", new { id=dep.DepartmentID}, null) %></td>
        <td><%: dep.DepartmentType.Type %></td>
        <td><%: dep.DepartmentStatus.Status %></td>
        <td><%: Html.ActionLink("Withdraw", "Withdraw", "Team", new { id = Model.personalInfo.PersonID, dep = dep.DepartmentID}, null)%></td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
```

The controller method that I am trying to call is this:

```
public ActionResult Withdraw(int personID, int departmentID)
    {
        .....
    }
```

How can I make this work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your parameters names do not match those sent by the action link. Try like this:

```
public ActionResult Withdraw(int id, int dep)
```

or update your ActionLink parameter names to match those of the action:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Withdraw", 
    "Withdraw", 
    "Team", 
    new { 
        personID = Model.personalInfo.PersonID, 
        departmentID = dep.DepartmentID
    },
    null
) %>
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Withdraw(int personID, int departmentID)
```

is going to work.